# Vue js multiselect - having custom suggestion text

Tags: vue.js, multi-select

I am using [vue multiselect plugin](https://github.com/monterail/vue-multiselect) in my Vue v.1x project. I am wondering how can I customise suggestion text like `Press enter to select` or `Press enter to remove`, when hovering over options? 
You can see the example in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqofkzxc/17/). I have tried with setting the `:selectLabel="Select"` but that didn't work.

Comment: In case you want to remove the labels, you can do so by passing a prop show-labels="false"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When sending props you need to use 'kebab-case'. So if the prop looks like selectLabel in the child, it should be pass like

```
:select-label="value"
```

Also, when sending the variable make sure to either to double quotes to send as a string, since the ':' before the prop tries to evaluate a variable.

Ex. The label should be 'Select'

```
:select-label="'Select'"
```

Ex. 2. The label should use a variable 'xyz' defined in the component

```
:select-label="xyz"
```

Comment: The other one is :deselect-label